# What would be the best approach to query eloquent relatioships where keys are on the same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Considering this table

**Services Table**

| id | company_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |

And this model

**CategoryModel.php**

```php
    public function companies():Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => CompanyModel::whereHas('services', function ($q) {
                $q->where('category_id', $this->id);
            }),
        );
    }
```

Considering that the `services` table holds both `company_id` and `category_id` columns what would be the best approach to query companies relationship that have services under the current category (The `companies` table does not have a `category_id` column), my current implemetation is not optimal as it does not allow me to perform any relationship constrains.

**EDIT**

Each company offers multiple services and each service belongs to a single category.

I also have a `reviews` table (related to each service) with a `rating` column
The above query worked efficiently until I needed to constrain/order categories based on the `reviews` table.

**CategoryModel.php**

```php
    public function scopeHasReviews($query)
    {
        $query->whereHas('companies', fn ($q) => $q->whereHas('reviews'));
    }
```

This ofcourse will not work since there is no relationship.

Comment: What error or problem are you facing with above relationship call? Also, I am not sure if you have modelled you db structure, this is what I am assuming. Each company could offere multiple service, and each service belongs to one category right? Or could one service be in more than one category?

Comment: I don't face any errors with the above, but consider a senario where I want to constrain results probably with scopes based on the companies table, this wont be posible.
Each company offers multiple services and each service belongs to a single category.

Answer (score 1):

Using Attribute in this context is dangerous, because it can lead to N+1 problems. This is a usual many-to-many relationship, so it needs to be implemented in models:

Category.php

```
public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'services');
}
```

Company.php

```
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'services');
}
```

Further, since it is not clear exactly what problem must be solved - I will write an example with sorting by number of reviews:

Review.php

```
public function scopeWhereRawService(Builder $query, string $service): Builder
{
    return $query->whereRaw('service_id = ' . $service);
}
```

Company.php

```
public function reviews(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Review::class, Service::class);
}

public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'services');
}

public function categoriesOrderedByReviews(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->categories()->withCount([
        'reviews as reviews_count' => fn(Builder $q) => $q->whereRawService('services.id')
    ])->orderByDesc('reviews_count');
}
```

Category.php

```
public function reviews(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Review::class, Service::class);
}

public function companies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'services');
}

public function companiesOrderedByReviews(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->companies()->withCount([
        'reviews as reviews_count' => fn(Builder $q) => $q->whereRawService('services.id')
    ])->orderByDesc('reviews_count');
}
```